# Object copy phase in GC taking too long

Tags: java, jvm, garbage-collection, garbage

My G1 pause GC runs for more than 10 seconds and almost all the time is taken by the object copy phase, can anyone help out with why this might be ?

```
2023-06-08T11:52:05.513+0000: 699700.262: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 11.3738011 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 10961.5 ms, GC Workers: 4]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 699700262.6, Avg: 699700262.7, Max: 699700262.9, Diff: 0.3]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 1.2, Avg: 1.5, Max: 1.7, Diff: 0.5, Sum: 6.2]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 2.5, Avg: 2.5, Max: 2.6, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 10.1]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 27, Avg: 37.2, Max: 45, Diff: 18, Sum: 149]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 1.7, Avg: 1.7, Max: 1.8, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 7.0]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 10884.4, Avg: 10924.6, Max: 10955.6, Diff: 71.2, Sum: 43698.3]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 30.9, Max: 71.1, Diff: 71.1, Sum: 123.7]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 1.8, Max: 2, Diff: 1, Sum: 7]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 10961.1, Avg: 10961.3, Max: 10961.4, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 43845.4]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 699711224.0, Avg: 699711224.0, Max: 699711224.1, Diff: 0.0]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.5 ms]
   [Other: 411.8 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 410.2 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.4 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.1 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.8 ms]
   [Eden: 1701.0M(143.0M)->0.0B(133.0M) Survivors: 10.0M->20.0M Heap: 2333.5M(3072.0M)->625.5M(3072.0M)]
 [Times: user=0.32 sys=0.10, real=11.38 secs] 
2023-06-08T11:52:16.887+0000: 699711.636: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 11.3743214 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000482 seconds
```

Another curious thing here is [Times: user=0.32 sys=0.10, real=11.38 secs].
Why is the real time significantly higher than user and sys time? I read somewhere that this might be due to system swapping but I haven't been able to figure out why.

Comment: Don’t ask the same question again.